# How to set 1 to 001 by default

Tags: kotlin

I have a code generator, by default it will be a four letter code. I want to set that if user input 1, it will read 001 and return AAB

```
val unitNumber = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.unitNumber)
val code = arrayOf("A", "B", "C", "D","E","F","G","H","I","J")
val button3 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3)
val codeName = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.codeName)
val digit = unitNumber.text

    button3.setOnClickListener {

    val AOne = Random.nextInt(0,5)
    codeName.text = "Your Code is:"+ code[AOne] + code[digit[0].toString().toInt()] + code[digit[1].toString().toInt()] + code[digit[2].toString().toInt()];
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to the @wizardofOz's answer,

Obviously you would be using the [String.padStart](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/pad-start.html), to manipulate the string. But the problem is that you are not getting the value of `unitNumber.text` at the time the button is clicked.

You have to fetch the text value inside the click listener to get the recent value when the button is clicked:

```kotlin
button3.setOnClickListener {
    val digit = unitNumber.text.padStart(3, '0')
    val AOne = Random.nextInt(0,5)
    codeName.text = "Your Code is:"+ code[AOne] + code[digit[0].toString().toInt()] + code[digit[1].toString().toInt()] + code[digit[2].toString().toInt()];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [partStart](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/pad-start.html).

```kotlin
val digit = unitNumber.text.padStart(3, '0')
```

Comment: Tried, it constantly returns AAA doesn't matter what the input are, any idea why the input was not read?